# Ignore/skip weekends with strtotime

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using strtotime within a while statment to automatically update entries in a database.

It adds on an amount of days depending on what the user has stated in the previous page.

Using this code:

```
    $calendardate = strtotime ( '+'.$calendarday.' day' , strtotime ( $date ) ) ;
    $calendardate = date ( 'Y-m-d' , $calendardate );
```

How can I get it to skip weekends? I need to use the same variable ($calendardate) but I need it to ignore Saturdays and Sundays.

Any help is most appreciated :)

Comment: Which SQL are you using? MySQL?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$now = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$h = date("H:i:s");    
$two_weekdays_later = strtotime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($now)) . " +2 weekdays $h");
```

Answer (score 0):

In the end I settled on iterating day by day, testing if something is a Saturday or Sunday. Otherwise it's too hard to account for end of year etc. (granted I had other requirements too, like skipping other days than just weekends, but likely you'll end up with the same requirements one day - like skipping holidays etc.).

Answer (score 0):

Use the date function as follows:

```
if ((date("w", $calendardate) == 0) || (date("w", $calendardate) == 6))
{ 
  echo "weekend";
}
```

Sunday = 0, 
Saturday = 6

If you use `date("N", $calendardate)`, then the numbers run for 1 = "Monday" through 7 = "Sunday"

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Note that `$calendardate` needs to be a unix timestamp as per the specification in the link.

Comment: I can't seem to get it to work.

Basically here's what i'm trying to do:

User Selects date from datepicker --> User selects amount of days --> PHP code detects if any of the days the user selected are on a weekend --> if no, use while loop to enter the days into a database, if yes, skip them and enter them after the weekend.

Comment: Sorry Sorry Sorry 100x sorry, Saturday is number 6, not seven, see the link.

Comment: Yeah I noticed that and changed it to a 6 and it still doesn't work :(

Comment: BTW what idiot decided that the week begins on Sunday, everyone knows it starts on a `Monday`, saterday and sunday collectively are even called the weekEND /rant

Comment: Nevermind I sorted it by changing 'days' to 'weekdays' in the first strtotime bit.