# PHP - How to get days, weeks and months without weekends?

Tags: php

I'm stuck in getting weeks and months using PHP's **DateTime::diff** function.

Here's my code:

```
$start = new DateTime('2017-06-05');
$end = new DateTime('2017-06-07');
$end->modify('+1 day');

$interval = $end->diff($start);

// total days
$days = $interval->days;

// create an iterateable period of date (P1D equates to 1 day)
$period = new DatePeriod($start, new DateInterval('P1D'), $end);

// best stored as array, so you can add more than one
$holidays = array('2017-09-07');

foreach($period as $dt) {
    $curr = $dt->format('D');

    // substract if Saturday or Sunday
    if ($curr == 'Sat' || $curr == 'Sun') {
        $days--;
    }

    // (optional) for the updated question
    elseif (in_array($dt->format('Y-m-d'), $holidays)) {
        $days--;
    }
}

if($days <= 7) {
    echo $days." day".($days > 1 ? 's' : '');   
}

// I'm stucked here
```

I can get the number of working days, but I can't get the months and weeks.
Somebody help me about this?

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7189826/7956549

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
$interval = $date1->diff($date2);
echo $interval->m // month
$week = floor($date1->diff($date2)->days/7);
echo $week; //week
```